# IIS 7 Application Request Routing to a server that uses SSL and https

Tags: iis-7

I am using IIS 7's ARR module to set up a reverse proxy to a linux machine that holds an e-commerce portion of the site.  The proxy works, however when you get to the end of the checkout, the php site on the linux box redirects to an https url and this just keeps timing out.

I'm not sure if I also need the SSL on the Windows machine or what settings I need to get an https page to work with a proxy.

Thank you in advance,

Brenna Dyer

Answer (score 0):

I would enable failed request tracing in the ARR server to see if you can learn more.
One guess is that the you might be sending the wrong location to redirection to the client or you might be getting in a loop:
So ise fiddler or similar tool to inspect the location header sent in the redirect 301/302, make sure it is not the internal Linux ip or something that  the client cant get to.
Loop could be that
Php returns a 302 to Arr and Arr sends back to client with location header to ssl end point. assuming I the ArR server you hqve the endpoint it might be offloading (terminatibg) ssl, which means the request will goto linux again over http instead of HTTPS which might cause a redirect to Ssl and on and on...
Bottomline the use of fiddler and failed requwst tracing should give you the answer.